# Can I make MySQL check basic things like "unknown column" errors in CREATE STORED PROCEDURE?

Tags: mysql

Simple example:

```
CREATE TABLE Foo (id INT);

CREATE PROCEDURE Bar (x INT)
INSERT INTO Foo (id) VALUES (z);

CALL Bar(123);
```

Which gives

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 6: Unknown column 'z' in 'field list'
```

I would like errors such as this to be caught in the CREATE PROCEDURE statement. Surely this statement should not succeed if the procedure can't be called?!

I appreciate that not every possible error can be caught in advance but many, such as this, can.

Is there a way to make MySQL more strict about what procedures it allows to be created, refusing ones with "obvious" errors such as this? Or are there third-party tools which are better at reporting errors like this?

Comment: mysql only parses the `create` call for basic sql validity. it doesn't check "meta" things, like whether the specified fields/tables in any of the procedure's commands exist, not could it. e.g. if you're loading up a DB dump, that table might not exist yet at the point the procedure's loaded, but will be created later on.

Comment: Okay a referenced table might not exist yet but in my example there **IS** no other table, there's nothing that `z` might refer to. Also a sensible engine would emit at least a warning if the external table DOES exist and can be checked against. My question is can *any* tool do this, if MySQL won't?

Comment: asking for software/tools is explicitly off-topic.